# How to use variable inside variable in ansible jinja template

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am trying to set value in j2 template in ansible. But the variable contains index inside it.
For example:

```
lb_url: {{ lbip_{{index }}_url }}
```

But the above format doesn't work. What is the  right format to support this?

Answer (score 1):

Try *`lookup`* [*`vars`*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/vars.html#vars-lookup-templated-value-of-variables). See [*`Other operators`*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#other-operators) and the comment on [*`+ operator`*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#math).

```
lb_url: "{{ lookup('vars', 'lbip_' ~ index ~ '_url') }}"
```